# UFT is skipping few lines while running the scripts

Tags: vba, execution, hp-uft

While I am running the scripts in UFT it is not executing few lines. I tried in break mode also, if I give F10 for once it is like skipping few lines and stopping after almost 5 lines. I tried using "Msgbox" before and after the skipped line it showing the "Msgbox" properly only.

Comment: 1. What programming language you are using? 2. Could you please edit your post and add lines that are skipped plus 5 lines before and 5 lines after for the context?

Comment: I am using vb scripting

Comment: Still need code to understand what is wrong. Please add it to your question.

Comment: lines of the code are never skipped just like that. Also try pressing F11 instead of F10, it will execute the statements in correct flow line by line.

And please share the code

Comment: thanks bro its now working. I have checked using F11 and found that all the lines are being executed

Comment: Good to know it solved your issue. Just posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Press F11 instead of F10, F11 is step into and F10 is step over.

F11 is Used to execute each and every Step. Steps into the Function/Action and executes line by line. It pauses on each line after execution.

For more information please refer the below link:

http://qtpexpertise.blogspot.in/2008/04/step-into-step-out-and-step-over.html